# Error: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) (" in Angular2+

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement as below in .html(template) of angular4 (code below) 
Here, How to handle multiple parentheses and curly braces and fix this bug?

```
But getting error as:-
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
```

### app.component.html

```
<div>
    <code>
        <pre>
            @Component({
                selector: 'app-projection',
                templateUrl: './projection.component.html',
                styleUrls: ['./projection.component.css']
            })
        </pre>
    </code>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message clearly suggests,

> Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your
>   template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("

Ensure that you are adding a **'** (quote) before your **{** character, You should modify your code as,

```
<div>
    <code>
        <pre>
            @Component({{ '{' }}
                selector: 'app-projection',
                templateUrl: './projection.component.html',
                styleUrls: ['./projection.component.css']
            })
        </pre>
    </code>
<div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The solution does not work, still getting error . Hope you will display it on stackblitz.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr Sorry for the delay, I've updated my answer above, I've verified that it is working fine, Checkout the stackblitz link here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyozcc , Also mark it as answered if you find it useful ;-)

Comment: Thanks, It means for every  {  we have to replace it by {{ '{' }}

Comment: Yes!! Exactly!!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Why are you trying to declare a component "inline" in your HTML?.

You should declare a component in a separate file, and then use the selector to use it in HTML

e.g.

```html
<pre>
  <app-your-component-selector></app-your-component-selector>
</pre>
```

**ORIGINAL**

The error is suggesting that you have an additional **{** in your HTML, something like this maybe

```html
<div> { --This will cause the error </div>
<div> { {{'This too'}} </div>
<span id="{{maybeHere}"> </span>
```